# How to get image upload date/time from Docker Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I need to get the image upload date from a `Docker Registry`

I currently use the following https://registry/v2/repository/manifests/tag which gives me `Creation Date`. This is stale in most cases. I want to know when something was uploaded.

If I can't get this, is there a way to do `docker build` and specify and date/time which could be used in place of the `Creation Date`?

An example of the manifest I'm getting which shows the only dates available are the v1Compatibility/created:

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "users/jesaremi/baseimage",
   "tag": "6a69f60507f029f76ff102aa1b89b562d2d784dfdbfef38cb0ed5c0b61a188ff",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:7c9d20b9b6cda1c58bc4f9d6c401386786f584437abbe87e58910f8a9a15386b"
      }
   ],
   "history": [
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"architecture\":\"amd64\",\"config\":{\"Hostname\":\"\",\"Domainname\":\"\",\"User\":\"\",\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":false,\"AttachStderr\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Env\":[\"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\"],\"Cmd\":[\"sh\"],\"ArgsEscaped\":true,\"Image\":\"sha256:758a17a836a4c09586a291c928d1f0561320e252d07c4749e14338daefe84b18\",\"Volumes\":null,\"WorkingDir\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"OnBuild\":null,\"Labels\":null},\"container\":\"e30cd53834b3dfdb989c63cc73f4f31f404c7a6a0c0e9d6b9e3e8451edd72596\",\"container_config\":{\"Hostname\":\"e30cd53834b3\",\"Domainname\":\"\",\"User\":\"\",\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":false,\"AttachStderr\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Env\":[\"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\"],\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh\",\"-c\",\"#(nop) \",\"CMD [\\\"sh\\\"]\"],\"ArgsEscaped\":true,\"Image\":\"sha256:758a17a836a4c09586a291c928d1f0561320e252d07c4749e14338daefe84b18\",\"Volumes\":null,\"WorkingDir\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"OnBuild\":null,\"Labels\":{}},\"created\":\"2019-09-04T19:20:16.230463098Z\",\"docker_version\":\"18.06.1-ce\",\"id\":\"a91ec18e2f45c300f1df0a23ac04c1396d791c6c387dd5e16e44dc96a4fc309d\",\"os\":\"linux\",\"parent\":\"bd5fbbc2870744fe1d37bbd120eebe4c441f8401c54b04b8ae0f9f625936f4c3\",\"throwaway\":true}"
      },
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"bd5fbbc2870744fe1d37bbd120eebe4c441f8401c54b04b8ae0f9f625936f4c3\",\"created\":\"2019-09-04T19:20:16.080265634Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:9151f4d22f19f41b7a289e87aa9cfba3956ffd27746cb3b171b9bd2cb7e6c313 in / \"]}}"
      }
   ],
   "signatures": [
      {
         "header": {
            "jwk": {
               "crv": "P-256",
               "kid": "3NQM:K5YD:M3XF:EKJD:4S64:3772:BJOT:JIMR:NX4R:2XYS:IDNA:NOKL",
               "kty": "EC",
               "x": "k6pZfyr-dKYLri5KJCL70UmNLCQnfUh2lAC_nDK9PVw",
               "y": "MhrKOUbx1sgsbF0kG9d5bfvkVaxaFWiKlWTwgFyHkbQ"
            },
            "alg": "ES256"
         },
         "signature": "klE8-cWOS1GZenBB7CPXYUK8VWmqiVQaFfWGgBQPn_L8iayojGEUc9D_06WCUdAqL7upvNIxcCPXJvZMORLn_Q",
         "protected": "eyJmb3JtYXRMZW5ndGgiOjIxOTksImZvcm1hdFRhaWwiOiJDbjAiLCJ0aW1lIjoiMjAxOS0xMC0yM1QyMTo0MTozM1oifQ"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: you can tag your image with date while building `docker build . -t $(date +"%m-%d-%y")`

Comment: Yes I could. That's what i ended up doing for now. I wanted to know if there's a real solution to this